# Unable to Update Revit Model for Basic Viewer

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge

I am trying to set up a Revit model viewer that gets updates when someone changes a model. I am not a Revit pro at all so bear with me. I've successfully uploaded a model up on a server which is pretty neat, but if I update my model and run the upload again of the same filename (but different contents) I'm given a message that my upload is complete immediately and no update occurs.

I've followed two guides to get this set up
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-viewer/

The above allowed me to set up the html form and bucket and everything

And I copied this code https://github.com/jaimerosales/modelderivative-nodejs-tutorial/blob/master/uploader.js as the uploader. I run `uploader.js` after I've updated my revit model and I see no update on my server. The only difference on the CLI is that the first time I run `uploader.js` I see:

```
**** Getting File Manifest Status
The status of your file is pending Please wait while we finish Translating your file
The percentage of your file is 0% complete
```

After the second time I run `uploader.js` (after updating the model) I see

```
**** Getting File Manifest Status
**** success
**** complete
**** Your File is ready for viewing
```

So it looks like there is no upload even happening anymore and it just takes on the file that is already uploaded. I've looked into https://www.npmjs.com/package/forge-apis and the various endpoints, but none seem to be what I am looking for. Is this an intended feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution, you can probably rename your revit file and upload and it’ll generate a new object name which will force the translation.

Furthermore, you can see here in the uploader.js file that the translateFile wrapper on the forge-apis derivativeApi translate endpoint that’s a Boolean parameter if it should retranslate the same model:

```
 @param {Boolean} opts.xAdsForce `true`: the endpoint replaces previously translated output file types with the newly generated derivatives  
`false` (default): previously created derivatives are not replaced  (default to false)
 * data is of type: {module:model/Job}
```

Therefore you can investigate how to call the uploader.js translateFile function with that specific options configuration, or you can use the forge-apis module directly and add xAdsForce:true specification to the header of the translate api call.